# Trying to execute a background command within a script

Tags: shell-script

In the following script:

```
#! /bin/sh
kate && echo hello &
sudo touch /root/test.txt
echo $? done
```

What I expect it to do is launch Kate in the background, but immediately ask me for my `sudo` password. However, though Kate is launched, `sudo` fails and this is what I receive:

```
$ ./test.sh 
[sudo] password for username: 
1 done
```

… and after I close Kate:

```
$ hello
```

… with the cursor being on the next line awaiting normal command input. The problem is the same whether I use `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

Comment: But I think it's correct. Second line (including shebang) will launch kate && echo hello in background, so after kate program will be successfully closed, echo will print "hello". After this you have there `sudo touch` and this sudo wants your password. `sudo` fails maybe because of permissions, but I am not sure. Try this command single in terminal and if it fails try before it `sudo su`.

Comment: How does sudo "fail"? It's prompting you to type a password... What happens if you type the correct password there? (I'm expecting it will touch the file as root and then print `0 done`.) Why the `echo hello`, what do you want to do with that?

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't even get the chance to input the password and `sudo` always fails.

Comment: The `echo hello` is just a placeholder for some other cleanup command I want to use in my actual script.

Comment: So it sounds like the line with `kate` in it is working as expected (hello is echoed after kate exits). But your `touch` command fails. What happens if you comment out/delete the `kate` line? does your touch command allow you to enter a password and complete successfully?